# How to make a model appear in front of AR Camera after the session starts using ARFoundation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I was looking to update the ARcamera position.I am doing ImageTracking project.It detects an image and a corresponding prefab is shown in front of the camera.It starts playing an animation.After the animation I want the prefab to come really close towards the camera.When I give the code `prefab.position=ARcamera.position;` after animation code,I think the prefab goes to the initial position where the ARCamera was when the app had started that is (0,0,0).

How to make the prefab come really close towards the front camera.

```
  speed = 10f;
  float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
  Showprefabs.transform.GetChild(0).position = Vector3.MoveTowards(Showprefabs.transform.GetChild(0).position,
                                             new Vector3(Arcam.transform.position.x, Arcam.transform.position.y + 0.2f,
                                             Arcam.transform.position.z + 6.3f), step);
```

//The values 0.2f and 6.3f I added using the Editor to make the prefab come near the camera(But in world position it is different.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I hope by "prefab" you mean already Instantiated `GameObject`. It makes no sense to move a prefab ;)

---

You tried to calculate the target position but did it with World-Space coordinates.

You probably want to do something like

```c#
var targetObject = Showprefabs.transform.GetChild(0);
var currentPosition = targetObject.position;

var targetPosition = Arcam.transform.position 
    // Place it 60cm in front of the camera
    + Arcam.transform.forward * 0.6f
    // additionally move it "up" 20cm perpendicular to the view direction
    + Arcam.transform.up * 0.2f;

targetObject.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPosition, targetPosition, step * Time.deltaTime);
```

---

If you want that movement a bit smoother so it moves slower if already close and faster if further away you might be interested in rather using [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) here

```c#
public float smoothFactor = 0.5f;

targetObject.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPosition, targetPosition, smoothFactor);
```

Where a `smoothFactor` of `0.5` reads: Every frame set the object to a position in the center of the `currentPosition` and `targetPosition`. A value closer to `0` results in slower movement, closer to `1` in faster reaching the `targetPosition`.

Note that actually this approach will never really fully arrive at the `targetPosition` but only come very very close but usually this doesn't matter in AR where the Camera constantly moves a bit anyway.

Comment: I tried the initial code but the prefab (instantiated gameObject) came towards left side of the camera not towards the centre of the camera.So in AR you cannot update the AR camera position?

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/ar-foundation-re-positioning-world-origin.540135/ Is this any kind of relevance.MakeContentAppearAt(Transform, Vector3).How to use this function?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct thing referenced in `Arcam`? Alternatively you could try `Camera.main.transform`

Comment: Yes,I have dragged and dropped.I tried Camera.main.transform but same came towards the left side.

Comment: Oh wait do you actually animate that specific object in the animator? The problem is as soon as you have any keyframe for a certain property in the Animator it will always "lock" and overwrite this property so there is no chance of overwriting it via a script! You could confirm that if you disable the Animator component after the animation.

Comment: Yes I am disabling the animator,otherwise it will not even move.`Showprefabs.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;`

Comment: Oh ok. Try to remove the `+ Arcam.transform.up * 0.2f` for now and see if that des the trick .. maybe the camera is oriented strange?

Comment: did you try my code? In what you just posted there is still only your version ...

Comment: @derHugo...I was testing similar code in another function which I did not use I was trying your code there .sorry .stupid me..Now the prefab went straight through the camera.I think adjusting the forward value will do the trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202186/discussion-between-zyonneo-and-derhugo).

Comment: Did take many builds and tested with different values along with Camera.main.transform.up and Camera.main.transform.forward . to make it somewhat near to screen targetObject.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPosition, targetPosition, smoothFactor); Looks like smooth factor has no effect changed to even 0.001 but still it is jumping to target destination....thanks.